# AWS Step functions: DistrbituedMap itemReader get bucket and key at runtime from state input in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I'm wondering if is there a way to get the bucket key from the input via CDK?

In the console, we can define:

```json
"ItemReader": {
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::s3:getObject",
        "ReaderConfig": {
          "InputType": "JSON"
        },
        "Parameters": {
          "Bucket": "my-bucket",
          "Key.$": "$.key"
        }
      }
```

But this doesn't seem to be working in CDK:

```js
const map = new sfn.DistributedMap(this, 'Parse the document', {
      itemReader: new sfn.S3JsonItemReader({
        bucket: myBucket,
        key: '$.key',
      }),
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CDK's [JsonPath.stringAt](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.html) helper method to use the `$.key` value from the state machine input:

```js
key: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.key"),
```

That will synth the expected `"Key.$": "$.key"` SDL.  Your code outputs `"Key": "$.key"`, which will cause step functions to treat `$.key` as a literal string.